# Calculation of Sun-Satellite and Moon-Satellite distance

Tags: jpl-horizons, ephemeris

I have the coordinates of a satellite in the Earth Centered Inertial frame.
I have calculated the Sun-Earth and Moon-Earth vectors using the JPLEphemeris package.

Now I have to calculate the Sun-Satellite and Moon-Satellite distances.

[image]

Is it correct, that `MS=ME+ES` and `SS=SE+ES`? I now the rules of vector addition, but I'm not sure about the directions of radius-vectors.

If it's correct- then, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use two distances to calculate a third distance for exactly the reasons you mention.

To get the distance from an Earth-orbiting satellite to the Moon, you need to use your vector diagram as follows to get the vector from the Moon to the satellite:

$$\mathbf{r_{MS}}=\mathbf{r_{ME}}+\mathbf{r_{ES}} $$

and then take the magnitude of the vector:

$$r_{ES} = |\mathbf{r_{ES}}|$$

So do your vector addition first, then calculate the distance from the resulting vector.

Because of the sizable distances and velocities compared to the speed of light, it's important to remember that observations (visual, radio, radar) will be complicated by light-time delays as well as [astronomical aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_of_light), and the rabbit hole goes deeper when you consider that very detailed and accurate calculations need to handle general relativistic (GR) effects upon space and time.

For light-time and aberration, many environments including JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), the Python package [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) (these are the two I use, there are certainly others) offer these corrections as built-in functions or options.

Comment: @Leeloo Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "directions of radius-vectors are correct?" Why not include a specific numerical example in your question? Show the x, y, and z components of each vector in an example. We can check an example to see if it is "correct".

Comment: I'm having trouble answering your comment because you've just shown a drawing with some labels. It certainly *looks correct* to me, I can understand it and I can write equations based on the drawing. I'm always more comfortable confirming with numbers though.